# Rarely, No value inserted in some column in my database. PHP MySQL HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql

I figuring out what is the problem here. Rarely(3 out 50 data), inserted to the database with incomplete data something like this:

[image]

PHP Codes for insert were correct. All value with have issue in no value in database are from `SELECT` tag HTML(year, month) . I don't know what is wrong here is the code for them.

```
     <select class="form-control" name="month" required>
           <option selected disabled>*Select Month</option>
           <option value="JANUARY">January</option>
           <option value="FEBRUARY">February</option>
           <option value="MARCH">March</option>
           <option value="APRIL">April</option>
           <option value="MAY">May</option>
           <option value="JUNE">June</option>
           <option value="JULY">July</option>
           <option value="AUGUST">August</option>
           <option value="SEPTEMBER">September</option>
           <option value="OCTOBER">October</option>
           <option value="NOVEMBER">November</option>
           <option value="DECEMBER">December</option>

       </select>


     <select class="form-control" name="year" required>
           <option selected disabled>*Select Year</option>
            <option value="2015">2015</option>
            <option value="2014">2014</option>
            <option value="2013">2013</option>
            <option value="2012">2012</option>               
       </select>
```

**EDIT: 1 **

This is how I insert in my data to database

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `subs` (firstname, lastname, time, year, month, tid, status, statusNew)
VALUES ('".$fn."', '".$ln."', '".$time."', '".$year."', '".$month."', '".$tid."', '".$st."', '".$st2."')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "ERROR!" . $conn->error;
}
```

**EDIT 2 **

Used by 15 users only with the same PC.

Thank you.

Comment: post your php code. How you are inserting values?

Comment: @JJ-SAMA Waiting for your php code, so we check what mistake are you doing

Comment: Edited, If gonna put the whole code it will be so long hehe.

Comment: Edited - It also used by 15 users only with the same pc.

Comment: is your missing value is also DECEMBER?

Comment: @VigneswaranS, Yes, because they started using the system by this month only,  DECEMBER is the month can be seen so far and the 2015.

Comment: You aren't using any prepared statements in your insert either.  This is very dangerous as the user can pass any values they want in, including arbitrary SQL commands.  Imagine if a user set their first name to:
'; drop table subs; --

Comment: what are you taking in` $year` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some browsers don't respect required attribute, as it is new in HTML5.  Moreover, you shouldn't trust client side validation, you should validate on the server as well.

```
 if(!isset($_POST['month']) || $_POST['month'] == '')
 {
   die ('A month is required to be set. Please use the back button and correct your form input.');
 }

 if(!isset($_POST['year']) || $_POST['year'] == '')
 {
   die ('A month is required to be set. Please use the back button and correct your form input.');
 }
```

Ideally, you'd want all values tested against a whitelist or regex to make sure that the input is valid to prevent bad data, and more seriously injection of arbirtrary SQL, JavaScript, PHP, or HTML.

That would more like:

```
 <?php
   $months = ['JANUARY','FEBRUARY','MARCH','APRIL','MAY','JUNE','JULY','AUGUST','SEPTEMBER','OCTOBER','NOVEMBER','DECEMBER'];
   if(!isset($_POST['month']) || !in_array($_POST['month'],$months))
   {
     die('The month isn't valid. Use back button, correct errors and resubmit the form.');
   }
```

Comment: I see, browser side issue? so if I remove the `value=""`  but it is so very rarely and the system only use by 15 person with the same pc.

Comment: Removing the value="" isn't a real solution.  You need to validate server side (for a lot more reasons than just a blank field now and then).  What if someone messed with the code of the page before submitting and injected SQL, HTML, or JavaScript? Never trust any input...  editing to be more complete.

Comment: Where can should add this code after the setting POST for submit  button? or after the insert code for database?

Comment: Before the insert, before anything touches the inputs, you should check them all for valid values.

Comment: After the declaring of variables?

Comment: Before you do anything else with the variables, you need to check the input.  You must assume that anyone using your form is potentially hostile hacker, looking to break in.  Please read up on var_filter and mysqli (or PDO) prepared statements.

Comment: error. `Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)`

Comment: It inputted value  as an 'Array'

Comment: You don't assign `$months` into `$month` nor insert `$months`. You still assign `$month = $_POST['month'];` and insert `$month` to your database -- after you know month is alright to use.

Comment: I will try your code with `month == ''` I hope it can fix this. I will observe this. Thanks.